# Modulo as activation function in neural network

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

Can we use a modulo function $f(x)$ as activation function in a neural network? Modulo function is monotonic and continuous (just like Relu) except at a finite number of points in the domain of our input data.
By modulo function $f(x)$ I mean

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
\vdots \\
  x+a \ \ \  \if \  -a < x < 0 \\
 x  \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \if\  \ \ \ 0 < x < a\\
 x-a \  \ \  \if  \ \ \ \ a < x < 2a \\
\vdots \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation} 
where a is a positive constant number and could be treated as hyperparameter for simplicity.

I want my output to take values between [0,1] and I am sampling the output from a gaussian distribution (, $\sigma^2$) where , $\sigma^2$ are the outputs of neural network. Hence the output may go outside the range [0,1]. I don't want to do clipping because it will create further problems in my network

I am new to Latex, sorry for not using a good formating.

Comment: Hue you are defining the Relationship between X and A.? And also what the goal that the available activation functions arent able to solve?

Comment: I want my output to take values between [0,1] and I am sampling the output from a gaussian distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$, $\sigma^2$ are the outputs of neural network. Hence the output may go outside the range [0,1]. I don't want to do clipping because it will create further problems in my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo function is not monotonic.
Even though it has a positive derivative except at points where it is not differentiable.
It is generally not recommended to use a non-convex Activation function. Hence, it is better to avoid it or change the structure of problem.